# problem with the roll of camera tracking an object

Tags: animation, camera, tracking, path

I created an camera following a path and tracking an object and I don't understand why this camera is rotating around his z-axis (for example between frame 50 and frame 100 ).
How can I solve this problem?
Thank you.

my file is dowloading here https://ufile.io/86d2b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Trackto constraint defines what axis points towards the target and which axis is considered "up". As the camera passes under the target, moving from being on one side to being on the other, the camera is being flipped to maintain the correct "up" orientation.

The solution is to change the constraint to use local space, this will change the initial orientation so you will also want to change the up axis to X

[image: trackto constraint settings]